# Issue importing external modules from component included with react-loadable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-loadable

I've a component loaded using react-loadable (5.4.0) that also loads some other local and external libraries:

```js
import { validationAPI, docstringAPI, autocompleteAPI } from 'utils/request';
import something from './something';

import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror';
import CM from 'codemirror';

import 'codemirror-docs-addon';
import 'codemirror-docs-addon/lib/main.css';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <div>What I do here it doesn't matter</div>
     )
  }
}
export default MyComponent
```

And this is the defined loadable:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Loading = () => (
  <div>
    Loading stuff
  </div>
);

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./MyComponent'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default (props) => (
  <LoadableComponent {...props} />
);
```

The issue I have: if the module I include asynchronously also **imports local modules never imported before** from my app, I get this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `LoadableComponent`.
>       in LoadableComponent
>       ...

For example: in the code above I have this `./something` imported. If this module has never been loaded before in my app I get the error above.

If I:

- import the module somewhere else (as for `validationAPI`, which is imported with no issues)
- remove the import

...the app works and I've the async behavior.

*Note*: If the imported stuff is used or not doesn't matters.

I also tried to move the `something` module somewhere else, but this seems not related to the module position or to relative import syntax.

Note also that externals libraries does not give me any issues: for example: the `codemirror` library is included only in that file, but it still works. **Only local modules** give me the issue.

The only workaround found: not import anything never imported before, but include the `something` module content inline in the component's file.

This is acceptable but bloat the file size a bit.

I'm not sure this is an issue with react-loadable or webpack or something else.
Any suggestion?

Comment: please show implementation of MyComponent.js

Comment: @SakhiMansoor is doesn't matter I tried removing all of the stuff, also a simple empty functional component break the app. Again: this is not related to the component itself but on the import (even if unused) stuff.
However: I will add an example component in any case

Comment: have you added babel dynamic import support?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor You mean plugin-syntax-dynamic-import? Is this still required? If I try any `import('someting').then()` I load it properly and I've webpack splitpoints working

Comment: I just tried, but does change nothing

Comment: @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" do you have it ?

Comment: "7.0.0-beta.54", this should be the version

Comment: @SakhiMansoor sorry, I can't easily migrate to babel 7

Comment: No. You need to do this if you're using stage-2. it's deprecated and will throw errors on console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue as you... Did you ever figure it out?

I was able to get it to work with Loadable.Map(). But I feel I shouldn't even have to do it this way!

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#loading-multiple-resources

Comment: As my `something` module was a "tiny" one I simply kept it imported in the main module. This was acceptable for my environment. `.Map`could be a good workaround too (I don't remember if I tried this at that time).
However in recent/modern React versions it's probably better to forget about `react-loadable` (which I hate a bit because it does not allow github issue) and use `React.lazy`.

Comment: ...sorry... I meant `Suspense`, not `.lazy`!